# Extract number from file name in python

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, python-3.x, file-handling

I have a directory where I have many data files, but the data file names have arbitrary numbers. For example

```
data_T_1e-05.d
data_T_7.2434.d
data_T_0.001.d
```

and so on. Because of the decimals in the file names they are not sorted according to the value of the numbers. What I want to do is the following:
I want to open every file, extract the number from the file name, put it in a array and do some manipulations using the data. Example:

```
a = np.loadtxt("data_T_1e-05.d",unpack=True)
res[i][0] = 1e-05
res[i][1] = np.sum[a]
```

I want to do this for every file by running a loop. I think it could be done by creating an array containing all the file names (using `import os`) and then doing something with it.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your files all start with the same prefix and end with the same suffix, simply slice and pass to `float()`:

```
number = float(filename[7:-2])
```

This removes the first 7 characters (i.e. `data_T_`) and the last 2 (`.d`).

This works fine for your example filenames:

```
>>> for example in ('data_T_1e-05.d', 'data_T_7.2434.d', 'data_T_0.001.d'):
...     print float(example[7:-2])
... 
1e-05
7.2434
0.001
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this will surely help but I have many files in the directory, there should a way to get all the filenames in an array automatically using the `os` library. Can you tell me how to?

Comment: @SthitadhiRoy: [`os.listdir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns a list of filenames in a directory. Remember to use `os.path.join(path, filename)` to make those into absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
# create the list containing all files from the current dir
filelistall = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
# create the list containing only data files. 
# I assume that data file names end with ".d"
filelist = filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.d'), filelistall)
for filename in filelist:
   f = open(filename, "r")
   number = float(filename[7:-2])
   # and any other code dealing with file
   f.close()
```